# How can I apply styles from a parent component to a child component of the form <Child style={'border':'1px solid red'}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

the child component (`ComponentA`) seems not to be inheriting the `style` I am defining from the parent component.

```
<ComponentA style="{'border':'1px solid red'}" />
```

how can I fix it?

```
<template>
  <div id="app"><ComponentA style="{'border':'1px solid red'}" /></div>
</template>
<script>
```

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-r9gcoa?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FComponentA.vue,src%2FComponentB.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `{}` from the style value and the quotes `'`:

```html
<ComponentA style="border:1px solid red" />
```

or add the binding sign `:` :

```html
<ComponentA :style="{'border':'1px solid red'}" />
```

> It is important to note that when applying attributes to components, the attribute will be added to the root element of that component(the first preceding child element).

Setting this on a component:

```html
<ComponentA class="tab" style="border:1px solid red" />
```

Equals to this on the root element:

```html
<div class="tab" style="border:1px solid red">Component A</div>
```

If the component has multiple root element, then you must specify which root element receives the data:

```html
<ComponentA class="tab" />
```

```html
<div :class="$atrr.class">Component A</div>
<div>Second root element</div>
```

Learn more: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#with-components